# query to add data from Node.js API to PostGIS Database

Tags: node.js, database, postgis, shapefile

I create a method to upload data to a PostGIS database from an API using Node.js, this is the method:

```
app.get('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const basePath = req.headers.path;
        const fileName = basePath.match(/[^\\/]+$/);

        const shpData = await shapefile.read(basePath);
        const columnNames = Object.keys(shpData.features[0].properties);
        const tableName = fileName[0].split('.')[0];

        const tableExistsQuery = `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = '${tableName}')`;
        const { rows } = await client.query(tableExistsQuery);
        const tableExists = rows[0].exists;

        if (!tableExists) {
            const createTableQuery = `
                CREATE TABLE ${tableName} (
                    gid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                    geom GEOMETRY,
                    ${columnNames.map(columnName => `${columnName} VARCHAR(255)`).join(', ')}
                )
            `;
            await client.query(createTableQuery);

            const uploadDataQuery = `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=${process.env.DATABASE} user=${process.env.USER} password=${process.env.PASSWORD} host=${process.env.HOST} port=${process.env.PORT}" ${basePath}.shp -nln ${tableName} -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI`;
            exec(uploadDataQuery, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
                    return;
                }
                if (stderr) {
                    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            });
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data uploaded in PostGIS database.' });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading data:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading data.' });
    }
});
```

And the query is:

```
const uploadDataQuery = `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=${process.env.DATABASE} user=${process.env.USER} password=${process.env.PASSWORD} host=${process.env.HOST} port=${process.env.PORT}" ${basePath}.shp -nln ${tableName} -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI`;
```

And it works only for a points shapefiles, but if I try to upload a poligon or line it fails:
2024-03-12 10:10:19 Error uploading data: RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView
2024-03-12 10:10:19     at DataView.getUint8 ()
2024-03-12 10:10:19     at new Dbf (/usr/src/app/node_modules/shapefile/dist/shapefile.node.js:80:20)
2024-03-12 10:10:19     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/shapefile/dist/shapefile.node.js:65:14
2024-03-12 10:10:19     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I tried with many types of shapefiles but I really don't know too much about PostGIS and Geoserver

Comment: Seems like you're trying to upload a shapefile which PostGIS thinks is invalid. Did you try to validate that shapefile?

Comment: Also why are you creating a table on request? This is veeeeeeery not how you should do things

Comment: I don't know much about how shapefiles works, could you please tell me what I could do in this case?

Comment: Please excuse my snarky comment, but how about you try to learn how to walk before trying to fly? The code you shared is a hot mess, and I'm not sure how you got to this point

Comment: I tried, I know, the code is a frankenstein of all info that I found and collect from other forums and docs. Appreciate it if you could please share any info that brings me an idea how to improve it

Comment: The error is clearly stated in your post `RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView`. Any shapefile validator should let you confirm that. Idk where you got such file from